# Login process using Ajax and refresh the whole page after successful login

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

On Google App Engine with python and a template system, I used jQuery Ajax to update a div during the user login process. The update message could be 'wrong id or password,' 'Welcome someUser, ' etc. However, after successful login, I would like to refresh the whole page such that some buttons may show up for certain users. The following is the Ajax code, and when a user clicks 'submit', only the <div id="login"> area gets updated. How do I refresh the whole page then?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
  $('#login').html(returnData);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.location.reload(true) should do the trick.

```
    $('.submitForm').ajaxForm({
        success: function(returnData) {
            $('#login').html(returnData);

            //check the response to see if it is a success message
            if(returnData == 'Welcome someUser'){
                 document.location.reload(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean to put the command in the <input ...> tag? Ajax would be of no use then?

Comment: no, just run that when the user successfully logs in. in your success function. It will literally refresh the whole page.

Comment: I don't quite get your idea. Only in the python program, does the system know if the login is successful. How do I use that statement in my python program?